# Chat client not sending messages

Tags: java, tcp

I am making a chat system in Java. It doesn't throw any errors or anything and I can't see anything that I have done wrong, but when I try to send something to the server it is not received.

*Server:*

```
package net.murplyx.chatserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static ServerSocket server;
    public static ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    public static ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        server = new ServerSocket(1234);

        while (true) {
            Socket c;

            while ((c = server.accept()) != null) {
                clients.add(c);
            }

            for (int i = clients.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                c = clients.get(i);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));

                if (in.ready()) {
                    messages.add(in.readLine());
                }
            }

            for (int i = clients.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                c = clients.get(i);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream());

                for (int j = 0; j < messages.size(); j++) {
                    String m = messages.get(j);

                    out.println(m);
                }
            }

            messages.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

*Client:*

```
package net.murplyx.chatclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);

        while (true) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            if (in.ready()) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            }

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String ln = input.readLine();

            if (ln != null) {
                out.println(ln);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you attach the debugger to your server implementation and see if anything's reaching the socket?

Comment: @DavieBrown Just did that and nope the server wont recieve anything

Comment: Is client getting connected?

Comment: There are few concerns in your implementation. Use 2 threads for listening and writing. In your Servercode if there is one client it will not go to listening loop. Other thing is u have use a if(in.ready()) sinve client still haven't send anything this condition is false and it will exit the loop